# Java, instanceof a subclass rather than a superclass

Tags: java

I know I probably have a poorly designed program if I have to ask this question. How can I make sure that an object is a subclass type rather than the subclass's parent?

For instance:

```
if (r instanceof subclassRobot) {
  //method
}
```

I don't want this to execute if `r` is the parent. I only want this method executed if `r` is the subclass type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the class itself like this:

```
if(thing instanceof SomeClass.class && !thing.getClass().equals(SomeClass.class))
{
    // Thing can be any class that extends SomeClass,
    // but will not belong to SomeClass itself.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r.getClass().equals(subClass.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely fine code.

Your p is a reference to the family of classes that belong to the family of base class. o.

```
if (r instanceof subclassRobot) {
    //...
}
```

is just fine to check if you are actually pointing to the instance of `subclassRobot`